# Confuso al implementar testing

Tags: java

Quiero implementar la integración continua en mi proyecto pero tengo ciertas dudas, supongamos que tenemos esto :

```
public boolean sumar(Persona person) {
    int result = 0;
    List<Personas> personas = null;

    try {           
        jdbcService.save(Personas.class, person);
        personas = jdbcService.list(Personas.class);
        result = utilsService.sum(personas);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

- Como harias vosotros para probar los 3 métodos con Mock
- ¿Qué diferencia hay entre test unit y de integración?

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando mucho mucho mucho, los unitarios son para probar la funcionalidad y los de integración la funcionalidad dentro de un entorno (con otros sistemas como por ejemplo una base de datos).

En cuanto a lo que preguntas de como hacer test, yo te puedo orientar sobre como hacerlo con Mockito. Es bastante fácil, por ejemplo, tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
UtilService util = Mockito.mock(UtilService.class);
[Mi objeto con el método suma].setUtilSerive(util); (o en el constructor)
```

e invocar [Mi objeto con el método suma].suma(xxx);

para modificar el comportamiento del mock puedes usar `when`. Algo así:

```
Mockito.when(util.sum(20)).thenReturn(xxxx);
```

básicamente, lo que hace es que le dices que cuando invoques el método con el valor 20 devuelva XXXX (lo que sea).

Si quieres ampliar más información sobre mocks con Mockito, te recomiendo que pases por la página de mockito: http://site.mockito.org/

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Primero, aquí no se prueban tres métodos. Se prueba uno (`sumar`).

Los tests unitarios se hacen a partir del código. No conozco las dependencias de `jdbcService.save` o `utilsService.sum`, así que no puedo escribir tests unitarios.

Y sería algo así

```
 JdbcService jdbcService =
    mock(JdbcService.class);
 UtilsService utilsService =
    mock(UtilsService.class);

 List<Persona> lista =
   new ArrayList<>();
 when(
   jdbcService.list()).
   thenReturn(lista);
 doReturn(69).
   when(utilsService).
     sum(eq(lista));

 ... Crear instancia del objeto, inyectar mocks

 assertEquals(
    "El resultado no coincide",
    69,
    resultadoDeSumar);
 ... y si acaso...
 verify(
    jdbcService, times(1)).
    save(
      eq(Personas.class),
      eq(miObjetoPersonaQuePasePorParámetroASumar));
```

Los tests de integración se hacen sin sustituir los módulos por dependencias, de forma que compruebas que no haya errores causados por discrepancias entre lo que se supone que hacen las dependencias y lo que hacen de verdad. Pero, naturalmente, al tratar con más clases son mucho más complejos de implementar.